# How to insert multiple records and create mapping table between old and newly created items

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm inserting multiple records into a table A from another table B.

```
INSERT INTO A (fname, lname)
OUTPUT inserted.ID INTO @outputA
SELECT fname, lname FROM B
```

The @outputA holds newly created Ids for table A.

I have another table C that holds the mapping between tables A and B.

```
declare @tableC table (IDtableA int, IDtableB int)
```

How can I add the values to the mapping table with the corresponding id values?
Something like that

```
INSERT INTO C (IDtableA, IDtableB)
VALUES (@outputA.ID, B.ID)
```

Comment: Use `INSERT .... SELECT FROM` instead of `INSERT VALUES`

Comment: INSERT VALUES was just the example. I don't know how to combine the data from the two tables @outputA and B

Comment: Have you tried `INSERT ... SELECT` ?

Comment: I don't know how to combine the data from the two tables @outputA and B since they have no matching columns

Comment: Surely the `fname` and `lname` columns will match in both `A` and `B`? Or do you allow duplicate values in those columns?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot use `OUTPUT` in an `INSERT` to get columns that are not in the `inserted` table. Instead you need to hack it with `MERGE`

```sql
DECLARE @outputA TABLE (IDtableA int, IDtableB int);

MERGE A  -- this is the target to insert
USING (
    SELECT fname, lname
    FROM B
) B     -- this is the source
ON 1=0  -- never match
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (fname, lname)
    VALUES (B.fname, B.lname)
OUTPUT inserted.ID, B.ID
  INTO @outputA (IDtableA, IDtableB)
;

INSERT INTO C (IDtableA, IDtableB)
SELECT o.IDtableA, o.IDtableB
FROM @outputA o;
```